# Can I pass a variable from python to bash file?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, sed

I have a bash file with a bunch of sed commands like this :

`sed -i 's/hello my name is Thibault/hello my name is Louis/g' "$1"`

so for now i'm doing all of this "by hand", however, I have a python script with a tkinter GUI and several input fields for the user. I would like to find a trick so that if the user inputs "hello my name is Olivia" in the text field then the regex would look like this:

`sed -i 's/hello my name is Thibault/hello my name is Olivia/g' "$1"`

So I was thinking that i could store the python text input result in the variable to have the regex look like this:

`sed -i 's/hello my name is Thibault/$my_variable/g' "$1"`

but i don't know how or if this is even possible. Lastly I want to mention that i know i could just ask for the user input in the bash script but this is for my first internship and I have to go through the python GUI.

Edit: **i'm on windows 10 if this is any important**

Comment: Take a look at Python's `subprocess` module, which can be used to run external programs (such as `sed`).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204662/how-to-pass-a-python-variable-into-a-bash-script.  Note that if you use a bash script just to use `sed`, python has all that builtin.

Comment: @Nic3500 really ? I've never done python before this project and i'm only a first year cs student, so i don't know lots of pythons function yet. i've seen the replace() function but this only worked if i want to change one occurence of a specific string, however for mùy task I need to replace 18K+ occurences of a word or sentence into  another. Can that be achieved with pure python? also i'm on windows 10, will it work if i use sed command outside of bash file ? also I Checked your link thats a great idea. But i'm interested in knowing more about doing it with built-in python

Comment: If you have many replacements to do, it will run faster in pure Python than calling bash over and over, since it will create a new instance of shell every time.  To decide how to best implement it in Python, detailed requirements are needed.  Basic exemple: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch04s04.html.  For `string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)`, if count is not set, it will replace all occurences.  The fact that you are on Windows does not change anything if you do it in Python.  It has an impact if you are using bash.

Comment: ah, if you are going to learn Python, go for Python 3.  Not 2.  Reference for other replacement solutions: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-str-replace-translate-re-sub/

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
import os

original_text = 'hello my name is Thibault'
new_text = 'hello my name is Louis'
filename = 'test.txt'
os.system (f'sed -i "s/{original_text}/{new_text}/g" {filename}')
```

Comment: ok i will try that thanks :) does this work if i'm on windows 10?

Comment: @LouisWheelz I've only tried it on linux.

Comment: @LouisWheelz : You did not specify the operating system you are using. My guess is that on Windows, `os.system` is using CMD or powershelll to run the command, so you could try it first on those before calling it from Python.

Comment: There is no `sed` on Windows (unless installing it specifically).

Answer (score 0):

For passing data (in your case: some string) from your Python program to a subprocess running a bash script, you have first of all the same options like when calling one bash script from another one: Either design the called script to expect positional parameters (use it as `$1` for example) and pass the string as parameter. For instance, if the string is stored in the Python variable *parameter*, it would look like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call ['bash', './script_to_be_called', parameter]
```

The other possibility is to design the bash script so that it expects the string to be stored in a variable of a certain name (use it as `$PARSTRING` for instance) and pass the data via the environment:

```
import os
os.environ['PARSTRING']=parameter
subprocess.call['bash', './script_to_be_called']
```

If the "script" executes only a single command, you could alternatively synthesize the command line in your Python program. Assume that you have a string *bashcommand*, which already holds the **complete command** which is supposed to be executed by bash, you could do a

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call ['bash', '-c', bashcommand]
```

While this should answer your question, I can't help but pointing out, that for executing a single external command, I would **not** create a **shell** process, but invoke this program directly as a child process. Also don't forget that spawning a child process takes time, and if you have many such invocations, it might make sense to redesign your approach, for instance by doing everything inside Python, or having only one child prcocess which gets as input the data for all the substitutions to be performed (typically via a file).

Comment: I think doing everything in python will indeed be more efficiant, I will try to use  the replace function, thanks a lot for your detailed answer.